# Spark Error when unpacking items from tuple in RDD

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I wrote a script on Jupyter notebook to read an RDD and perform operations. The script works fine on Jupyter.

```
rdd=   [('xxxxx99', [{'cov_id':'Q', 'cov_cd':'100','cov_amt':'100', 'cov_state':'AZ'},
                  {'cov_id':'Q', 'cov_cd':'33','cov_amt':'200', 'cov_state':'AZ'},
                  {'cov_id':'Q', 'cov_cd':'64','cov_amt':'10', 'cov_state':'AZ'}],
                  [{'pol_cat_id':'234','pol_dt':'20100220'}],
                  [{'qor_pol_id':'23492','qor_cd':'30'}]),

     ('xxxxx86', [{'cov_id':'R', 'cov_cd':'20','cov_amt':'100', 'cov_state':'TX'},
                  {'cov_id':'R', 'cov_cd':'44','cov_amt':'500', 'cov_state':'TX'},
                  {'cov_id':'R', 'cov_cd':'66','cov_amt':'50', 'cov_state':'TX'}],
                  [{'pol_cat_id':'532','pol_dt':'20091020'}],
                  [{'qor_pol_id':'49320','qor_cd':'21'}]) ]
              

def flatten_map(record):
    # Unpack items
    id, items, [line], [pls] = record
    pol_id = pls["pol_cat_id"]
    pol_dt = pls["pol_dt"]
    qor_id = pls["qor_pol_id"]
    for item in items:
        yield (id,item["cov_id"],item["cov_cd"], item["cov_amt"], item["cov_state"], pol_id, pol_dt, qor_id), 1


 result = (rdd
    # Expand data
    .flatMap(flatten_map)
    # Flatten tuples
    .map(lambda x: x[0],)))
```

However, when converting to a Python script, I get an error:

> 2019-10-01 14:12:46,901:ERROR: id, items, [line], [pls] = record
>
> 2019-10-01 14:12:46,901:ERROR:ValueError: not enough values to unpack
>
> (expected 1, got 0)

Any suggestions? Is there a difference between how Python handles this on notebook vs .py?

Comment: Usually IDE versus executable errors are because there were some variables stored in memory you weren’t aware of. Is this the entire script in both Jupiter and what you’re executing? How are you executing this script on the command line?

Comment: I'm moving this to a .py file and executing the .py file with python file.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just some mistakes taking the right value for the right variables.

Please go through the following code:

```py
rdd = [('xxxxx99', [{'cov_id':'Q', 'cov_cd':'100','cov_amt':'100', 'cov_state':'AZ'},
                  {'cov_id':'Q', 'cov_cd':'33','cov_amt':'200', 'cov_state':'AZ'},
                  {'cov_id':'Q', 'cov_cd':'64','cov_amt':'10', 'cov_state':'AZ'}],
                  [{'pol_cat_id':'234','pol_dt':'20100220'}],
                  [{'qor_pol_id':'23492','qor_cd':'30'}]),
     ('xxxxx86', [{'cov_id':'R', 'cov_cd':'20','cov_amt':'100', 'cov_state':'TX'},
                  {'cov_id':'R', 'cov_cd':'44','cov_amt':'500', 'cov_state':'TX'},
                  {'cov_id':'R', 'cov_cd':'66','cov_amt':'50', 'cov_state':'TX'}],
                  [{'pol_cat_id':'532','pol_dt':'20091020'}],
                  [{'qor_pol_id':'49320','qor_cd':'21'}]) ]
def flatten_map(record):
    # Unpack items
    id, items, [line], [pls] = record
    pol_id = line["pol_cat_id"]
    pol_dt = line["pol_dt"]
    qor_id = pls["qor_pol_id"]
    for item in items:
        yield (id,item["cov_id"],item["cov_cd"], item["cov_amt"], item["cov_state"], pol_id, pol_dt, qor_id), 1
result = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rdd).flatMap(flatten_map).map(lambda x: x[0])
result.collect()
```

```
# OUTPUT
[('xxxxx99', 'Q', '100', '100', 'AZ', '234', '20100220', '23492'), ('xxxxx99', 'Q', '33', '200', 'AZ', '234', '20100220', '23492'), ('xxxxx99', 'Q', '64', '10', 'AZ', '234', '20100220', '23492'), ('xxxxx86', 'R', '20', '100', 'TX', '532', '20091020', '49320'), ('xxxxx86', 'R', '44', '500', 'TX', '532', '20091020', '49320'), ('xxxxx86', 'R', '66', '50', 'TX', '532', '20091020', '49320')]
```

Comment: @algorythms Sure. Please select and upvote my answer too